# BCM43142 and linux kernel 4.15.0-24-generic

Tags: wifi, hardware

I've got trouble - wi-fi not working on 4.15.0-24-generic.

I tried rebuild module:

```
Building initial module for 4.15.0-24-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-24-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
```

wi-fi controller:

```
 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Now on old kernel -  4.13.0-45-generic.

/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log:

```
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom for kernel 4.15.0-24-generic (x86_64)
Mon Jul  2 19:49:31 MSK 2018
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c: In function ‘osl_os_get_image_block’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:1083:26: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘kernel_read’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  rdlen = kernel_read(fp, fp->f_pos, buf, len);
                          ^
In file included from ./include/linux/huge_mm.h:7:0,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:463,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/include/linuxver.h:65,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:25:
./include/linux/fs.h:2858:16: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘loff_t {aka long long int}’
 extern ssize_t kernel_read(struct file *, void *, size_t, loff_t *);
                ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:1083:37: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘kernel_read’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  rdlen = kernel_read(fp, fp->f_pos, buf, len);
                                     ^
In file included from ./include/linux/huge_mm.h:7:0,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:463,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/include/linuxver.h:65,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:25:
./include/linux/fs.h:2858:16: note: expected ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 extern ssize_t kernel_read(struct file *, void *, size_t, loff_t *);
                ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:1083:42: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘kernel_read’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  rdlen = kernel_read(fp, fp->f_pos, buf, len);
                                          ^
In file included from ./include/linux/huge_mm.h:7:0,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:463,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/include/linuxver.h:65,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:25:
./include/linux/fs.h:2858:16: note: expected ‘loff_t * {aka long long int *}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern ssize_t kernel_read(struct file *, void *, size_t, loff_t *);
                ^
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_init_timer’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2359:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(&t->timer);
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2360:10: error: ‘struct timer_list’ has no member named ‘data’
  t->timer.data = (ulong) t;
          ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2361:20: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  t->timer.function = wl_timer;
                    ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to download the package for 18.04LTS (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/bcmwl-kernel-source) and install  it using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works in Ubuntu 16.10 also

Comment: confirmation that it works on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: This worked on my Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS as well, thanks a lot for saving me a headache!

Comment: it works on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Grossoo!! estuve 1 dia buscando la solucion