# Wifi card not working Loki

Tags: release-loki, wifi, networking, internet

I have come to this issue since yesterday that the only way I can get internet from using my computer is by sharing my phone's connection via USB. My wifi card seems like it is not even activated.

I am running ElementaryOS Loki and it worked fine until I woke up my computer from sleep mode yesterday.

It should be important to know that I am running a dual boot and that wifi works fine on my Windows 7 system so it is not a hardware issue. When I run `lspci -nn | grep -i network` I get :

```
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

I tried updating my network card's drivers but it didn't work, at this point I don't really know what to to to get internet back normally on my computer..
Does any of you know where the issue come from and/or how to fix this?
I believe it could be the drivers not installing properly since there are a bunch of errors when I install them, in particular `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-24-generic` which I don't know how to fix.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BCM43142 and linux kernel 4.15.0-24-generic](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15842/bcm43142-and-linux-kernel-4-15-0-24-generic)

Answer (score 0):

Broadcom drivers reported to broke for many users after the kernel update.

Take a look at this post: [BCM43142 and linux kernel 4.15.0-24-generic](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15842/bcm43142-and-linux-kernel-4-15-0-24-generic/15855#15855)